What are the automorphisms of finite commutative groups？
What are the automorphisms of finite commutative groups？Is there a relatively complete conclusion? Although it can be decomposed into the direct product of cyclic groups, this question still seems very difficult.

I struggle to see how this is research level - the first hit for "automorphisms of finite commutative groups" on google scholar gives me the American Mathematical Monthly article in the answer below. This article states that the result is from at least 1907.
